# Does calling in find_elements...().text count as the find_elements function itself?

Tags: python, android, selenium, appium

I have code that takes all elements of a certain class and extracts a text element from it.

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
print(chatblocks)
chatblocktext = chatblocks[-3]
```

I am currently receiving a StaleElementReferenceException at the 3rd line.

Does calling in the .text function in line 3 run the find_elements function again? And why doesn't this Stale error show up on line 1?

To solve this, would loading in all the text into a list at line 1 work? I attempted this:

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView").text
```

But I received an error saying .text cannot work for list objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see line by line execution of

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
print(chatblocks)
chatblocktext = chatblocks[-3]
```

1. `find_elements` would return a list, in this case it is **chatblocks**
2. print the entire list, which typically should print webelements, not their `.text`
3. find the third element on left side after 0.

Now your questions :-

Does calling in the `.text` function in line 3 run the `find_elements` function again? And why doesn't this Stale error show up on line 1?

- No, it won't run again. it's a list in Python, so `find_elements` would have returned a list of webelement. at line 1, the elements are available.

for this :

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView").text
```

on a list you cannot do `.text` instead :

```
for chat in driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView"):
    print(chat.text)
```

Comment: Why would I be receiving a Stale error at line 3 if find_elements isn't run again?

Comment: What is the exact code your ran and what error you got ?

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_class_name` retrieves web element reference.
Actions like `element.click()` or `element.text` are trying to access the element on the page by this reference (pointer).
They do not trying to find the element again according to it's locator, they trying to access it by it's reference.
In case the element was changed from the moment the reference was collected, accessing element with no more relevant reference throws `StaleElementReferenceException` exception.
Also, `find_elements_by_class_name` retrieves a list of web elements, not a single web element.
You can not apply `.click()` or `.text` methods on a list of objects.
You can iterate over a list and apply a command on each element in the list, like this:

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
for el in chatblocks:
    print(el.text)
```

or

```
chatblocks = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
for el in chatblocks:
    print(el.click())
```

Comment: In this case, are there any methods of extracting text from the elements from the same line as the find_elements line? I have no idea what's causing the change in element between the two lines. 

The methods you gave are dandy but I'm concerned they would run into the same problem of the element changing between the lines.

Comment: if this is a "chat" it seems like it would be constantly updating.  That's the issue.  Your element references will pretty much always be stale by the time you use them.  You'd need to stop a script from updating the DOM to get at any of these elements.  It may be constantly polling or even have an open socket/stream?  (Which means you'd be better off capturing the incoming data instead of going through the DOM...)